# Manipulation of string list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "X", "0"}, {"a", "f", "z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "z", "1"}, {"a", "b", "x", "0"}};
```

The last field of each element of `lis` is either "0" or "1".

I need to convert the third field in each element to upper case and then determine if there are any two elements in the list which have now become duplicates, delete the duplicate, and then change the last field of the remaining element from the deletion pair from "0" to "1" to get:

```
res = {{"a", "b", "X", "1"}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}}
```

Making the third field upper case and deleting duplicates is simple, but I'm not sure how to convert the last field from "0" to "1".  Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: It seems that [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) is useful here:

`DeleteDuplicates[MapAt[ToUpperCase, lis, {All, 3}]] /. "0" -> "1"`

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ this would break if one of the non-duplicates elements has "0" in its 4th index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
First /@ 
 (GatherBy[MapAt[ToUpperCase, lis, {;;, 3}], Most] /. {{a__, "0"|"1"}, __} :> {{a, "1"}})
```

> {{"a", "b", "X", "1"}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}}

Also

```
Tally[MapAt[ToUpperCase, lis, {;; , 3}], Most[#] == Most[#2] &] /. 
  {{a__, b_}, c_} :> {a, c /. {1 -> b, _ -> "1"}}
```

> {{"a", "b", "X", "1"}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}}

and

```
SequenceReplace[Sort @ MapAt[ToUpperCase, lis, {;; , 3}], 
   {Repeated[{a__, _}, {2, ∞}]} :> {a, "1"}, ∞]
```

> {{"a", "b", "X", "1"}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}}

Answer (score 3):

This should also work:

```
#[[1]] /. {a_, b_, c_, _} :> {a, b, c, "1"} /; #[[2]] > 1 & /@ 
 Normal[Counts[MapAt[ToUpperCase, lis, {All, 3}]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "X", "0"}, {"a", "f", "z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "z", 
    "1"}, {"a", "b", "x", "0"}};

GatherBy[lis, {#[[1]], #[[2]], ToLowerCase[#[[3]]]} &] // 
   Replace[#, {a_List, b__List} :> {Most@a~Join~{"1"}}, 1] & // 
  Map[First] // SubsetMap[ToUpperCase, #, {All, 3}] &
```

or

```
(lis // Replace[#, {a_, b_, c_, d__} :> {a, b, ToUpperCase[c], d}, 
      1] & // GatherBy[#, Most] &) /. {{a_?VectorQ} :> a, 
  a_?MatrixQ :> {Splice@ a[[1, 1 ;; -2]], "1"}
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"a", "b", "X", "1"}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}}

Comment: I think the `0` in the first subset must be `1` (like @kglr)`

Comment: I have updated the answer, @eldo.

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy` for your last condition:

```
f1[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := {a, b, c, "1"};

f2 = Union @@ Values[GroupBy[#, Last, 
     f1 /@ MapAt[ToUpperCase, #, {All, 3}] &]] &;
```

Test:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "X", "0"}, {"a", "f", "z", "1"},
      {"g", "a", "z", "1"}, {"a", "b", "x", "0"}};

res = {{"a", "b", "X", "1"}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}};

f2@lis === res

(*True*)
```

Or using `SortBy` and `SplitBy`:

```
f3 = Union @@ Map[f1, SplitBy[
     SortBy[MapAt[ToUpperCase, #, {All, 3}], Last], 
     Last], {2}] &;

f3@lis === res

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{"a", "b", "X", "0"}, {"a", "f", "z", "1"}, 
  {"g", "a", "z", "1"}, {"a", "b", "x", "0"}};
```

Using `Counts`

```
With[{c = Counts @ MapAt[ToUpperCase, list, {All, 3}]},
 Join[
  MapAt[1&, {All, -1}] @ Keys @ Select[UnequalTo @ 1] @ c,
  Keys @ Select[EqualTo @ 1] @ c]]
```

{{"a", "b", "X", 1}, {"a", "f", "Z", "1"}, {"g", "a", "Z", "1"}}